# c++ inheritance compilation problem undefined reference to derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

```
class BaseClass {
public:
    BaseClass();
    virtual void vfunc1()= 0;
    virtual void vfunc2();
    virtual void vfunc3();
    virtual void vfunc4();
    virtual ~BaseClass();
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};

class SubClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    SubClass();
    virtual void vfunc1(); 
    virtual void vfunc3();
    virtual void vfunc5();
    ~SubClass();
private:
    int z;
};

int main()
{
    BaseClass *bc = new SubClass();
    return 0;
}
```

Error is the follow:

```
 Temp\ccsj6Duj.o:demo.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `SubClass::SubClass()' collect2.exe: 
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help i'm new c++:
The problem resides in inhwritance and vtable :
This is a demo for better understanding inheritance

Comment: Wheres your implementations? Since you have a `main` method there im guessing you dont have any which is your problem :p

Comment: I just want the code to compile but i cannot. Suggestions? Tips? Implementations examples ? . I just want bare minimum code possible for compilation . Thx for help

Comment: Bare minimum possible needs implementation, how does the compiler know what your class or function does if you dont tell it? You've got a linker error there because the compiler cant find the implementation of `Subclass`'s constructor

Comment: The code compiles; it fails to **link** because you provided no implementation for the code you declared would be part of your build. Ex:: Where is `SubClass::SubClass()` actually *implemented* ? I can see where it is *declared*, but where is the "there" ?

Comment: Well you're right it fails to link ... i'm just trying to have an .exe that does nothing with an empty class and another empty inherited class. Seems i have to read more. thx

Comment: @4rt1c0 You didn't implement `SubClass::SubClass()` anywhere in the shown code, but you use it when you call `new SubClass();`, so the compiler doesn't know what you want that constructor to do.

Comment: yes!!!!!! thank you !!!!!!! Zoe I love you !!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
virtual void vfunc1()= 0;
```

This code means that BaseClass is an abstract class. When an abstract class is inherited, **all pure functions must be implemented**, otherwise the inherited class is also an abstract class. (except for pure vitual destructors)

**Abstract classes are not allowed to define objects** and can only provide interfaces for inherited classes. And I think that's why you had an compile error.

Comment: even if i remove that line it won't link ... i wish empty implementation ... or bare minimum implementations that does nothing ... thanks ...

Comment: OP is overriding the pure virtual method with `virtual void vfunc1();` in `SubClass`, so `SubClass` will not be abstract. However OP seems to not provide implementations for *any* of the declared functions.